# Override mtdparts after kernel has booted

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, flash-memory

Information about mtd partitions can be passed to the kernel via the kernel command line (`mtdparts` parameter) or via the device tree.

Is it possible to override this after the kernel has booted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

[del_mtd_parttions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=del_mtd_partitions) is called only during cleanup.  There is no path where it is called prior to re-adding different partitions.